# How to convert datetime object into date?

Tags: python, django, datetime

I am getting the following error while trying to get date out of datetime object:

```
must be string, not datetime.datetime
```

the format of the timestamp is

```
Tue, 26 Apr 2016 22:12:00 +0530
```

Here is the models.py:

```
class Order(models.Model):
    ORDER_STATUS = (
        ('created' , 'Created') , 
        ('paid','Paid'),
        ('shipped','Shipped'),
        ('refunded','Refunded'),
        )

    status = models.CharField(max_length=120 , choices=ORDER_STATUS , default='created')
    cart = models.ForeignKey(Cart)
    user = models.ForeignKey(UserCheckout , null=True)
    address = models.ForeignKey(UserAddress , related_name='useraddress' , null=True)
    Order_total_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10 , decimal_places=2)
    order_id = models.CharField(max_length=20 , null=True , blank=True )
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True , auto_now=False)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.user)

class SubOrder(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey('orders.Order')
    store = models.ForeignKey(Store)
    store_order_id=models.CharField(max_length=300)
    items = models.ManyToManyField(StoreProduct,through=StoreOrderItem)
    read = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    store_order_amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=50 , decimal_places=2)
```

And here is the object class:

```
import datetime


class ChartData(object): 
    @classmethod  
    def check_order_data(self):
        data = {'order_numbers': [], 'order_price': [] , 'date' : []}

        orders = SubOrder.objects.all()

        for order in orders:
            print str(order.order.timestamp)
            print datetime.datetime.strptime(order.order.timestamp, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")
            data['order_numbers'].append(str(order.id))
            data['date'].append(order.order.timestamp)
            data['order_price'].append(int(order.store_order_amount))
            print data
        return data
```

Here is the traceback:

```
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  132.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py" in view
  71.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py" in dispatch
  89.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\Grooved2\grooved\src\store\views.py" in get
  560.      data = ChartData.check_order_data()
File "C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\Grooved2\grooved\src\store\utils.py" in check_order_data
  15.           print datetime.datetime.strptime(order.order.timestamp, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")
```

How can I resolve the above error? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`datetime.datetime.strptime()` is convert `string` to a `datetime` object.

`datetime.datetime.strftime()` is to convert `datetime` object to specified `string`

`datetime` to `string`:

```
>>> datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
'2016-04-26 22:22:39.720617'
```

`string` to `datetime`:

```
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime('2016-04-26 22:22:39.720617', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
datetime.datetime(2016, 4, 26, 22, 22, 39, 720617)
```

Answer (score 0):

Function [`datetime.datetime.strptime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) must receive a a `date_string` and a `string_format`.

If you want to get a string from a datetime.datetime object, you should use [`strftime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.strftime) function.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get date out of datetime object i used this:

```
datetime.datetime.strftime(order.order.timestamp, "%Y-%m-%d")
```